# How to initialize lookup-table static std::array, a private member of a class, defined with constexpr length based on bit length of int

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, initializer-list, stdarray

Trying to create a class which acts as a tool to amplify/attenuate some value based on lookup tables.

Foo.h

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

#include <array>
#include <limits>

class Foo
{
public: 
    Foo();
    ~Foo();

    static double applySomeFoo(double f, unsigned int amplify_by);

private:
    static constexpr int m_BITS_IN_INT {std::numeric_limits<int>.digits};

    static std:array<double, m_BITS_IN_INT> m_fooFactors /***?** Don't know what to put here! */;
    // **?** Tried {{}}, {} and nothing and {{...}} and {...} and {{{}}} then scratched head...
};

#endif
```

Foo.cpp

```
#include <assert>

#include "Foo.h"

double Foo::applySomeFoo(double f, unsigned int amplify_by)
{
    assert(amplify_by < Foo::m_BITS_IN_INT);
    return (f * Foo::m_fooFactors.at(amplify_by));
}

// FOO

Foo::Foo() : /**?** Don't know what to put here! */
{
    // ctor

    // Populate the lookup table
    int i {0};
    for(auto &x : Foo::m_fooFactors)
    {
        x = static_cast<double>(2 ^ i++);
    }
}

Foo::~Foo()
{
    // dtor
}
```

I'm new to C++.
It fails to compile and I don't really understand how to instantiate so I can then populate the static array with values since it has a compile-time-variable length.

So the question boils down to;
**Q. How can I ensure m_fooFactors is an instantiation of an array of zeros of the known fixed-length so I can then populate it in the class constructor?**

This EXAMPLE is a toy re. the m_fooFactors calculation, the actual calc is more complex, but gives you a flavor of my usage of the *std::array* as lookup-table.
I am using GCC and trying to make C++11 code.
I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: All your members are static, so initializing them in the constructor does not make much sense, initialize them [once](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3815b4fdc41606f6). If they are not always going to be the same, don't make them static.

Comment: Is this because the static contents of the class can be called WITHOUT an instance of the object, namely; double Boo = Foo::applySomeFoo(1.0, 2u); ?

Comment: So defining it MUST go into the header?

Comment: No, the out-of-line definition should usually go in a .cpp file.